# What does indexing syntax by parentheses instead of square brackets mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In Python (matplotlib package), I created an object of `ListedColormap` using the following line:

```
listed_color_map = ListedColormap(('red', 'green', 'blue'))
```

Then I saw a code retrieving the colors (e.g. green) like this:

```
listed_color_map(1)
```

Calling the previous line returns:

> (0.0, 0.5019607843137255, 0.0, 1.0)

I have never seen this kind of *Indexing* with parenthesis (square brackets don't work here). This looks for me exactly as like as calling a method. What is this syntax of retrieving the values from the `ListedColorMap` exactly?

And it can be also called like this:

```
listed_color_map = ListedColormap(('red', 'green', 'blue'))(1)
```

This seems to me just like calling a method immediately after calling the constructor which is a bit weird for me (in C family there is no equivalent to this).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but that's not indexing, it's a function call. `ListedColormap` must return a function. (or some other callable object)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I updated the question a bit and mentioned the constructor part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the instances are "callable" i.e. the class (or a parent of it) implements the `__call__` method. This [dunder method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) allows to "call" the instances with the parantheses.

For your very example, it turns out the parent of `ListedColormap` class, which is `ColorMap` class, implements dunder call method. We can see the source code of [ListedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html#ListedColormap) and its [parent](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html#Colormap) that implements that interface.

The doc of the `__call__` function reads

```
Returns
-------
Tuple of RGBA values if X is scalar, otherwise an array of
RGBA values with a shape of ``X.shape + (4, )
```

where `X` is your input, 1. In your second example, you are more or less doing the same thing: you're generating an instance of `ListedColormap` class and immediately "call"ing it with a scalar argument.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, a high quality answer with the best references. Many thanks!